# Jquery selector not working with Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, selector

I'm trying to create a script in the console that would output the nickname of the chat user.

**First let's try to do it with copy and pasting paths:**

We inspect the name in chrome console and copy its' selector:

```
acc > div.scrolledPart.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div:nth-child(6) > div > ul > li:nth-child(3)
```

assign the above path to variable user3

```
var user3 =$('#acc > div.scrolledPart.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div:nth-child(6) > div > ul > li:nth-child(3)');
```

Output the nickname of the user in alert

```
alert("3d user's nick is : " + user3.attr("nick"));
```

Username shows up in the alert successfully.

**Now let's try same exact steps only this time assigning the path to the variables:**

Inspect the list of users and assign it to userList variable.

```
var userList=$0;
```

Check to see if it's assigned correctly, seems to open up in the console, so the userList is correct.

Assign the third element of the userList collection to the user3 variable. (which should in theory be third user).

```
var user3=$('userList > li').eq(3);
```

Trying to output the user nickname to alert:

```
alert("3d user's nick is : " + user3.attr("nick"));
```

The alert is "undefined"!!!!

Can you help me figure out why the "nick" attribute is not being displayed correctly? I think the problem is in step 3, but it works if we copy and paste the selector from Chrome, but if we try to do exact same thing from variable it doesn't work. Below is the image of the problem.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWfoC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
var user3 = $('userList > li').eq(3);
```

`'userList'` is a string literal, not a variable.

In this case, to use the variable:

```
var user3 = userList.find(">li").eq(3)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting an error "VM971:1 Uncaught TypeError: userList.find is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:22"

Comment: @SSJ5Broli That is probably because `$` is not jQuery, it is just a reference to `document.querySelector`. [More details](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryselector)

Comment: Ok thanks, so it seems that if I wrap the userList variable in the $() to make it a jQuery object then the solution provided by freedomn-m would work: 

var user3 = $(userList).find(">li").eq(3);